# javascript regex to extract a word from middle of 6 sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

i have a string like following:

Assigned to *ram* on 2010-04-22 12:30:13.0

i need to extract the third word (ram). I tried the below regex, its not working.

/\s[a-zA-Z]*\s/

any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the `*` around `ram` a formatting or really exist in the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a regular expression, why not just [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the string on spaces and grab the third one?

```
var s = "Assigned to ram on 2010-04-22 12:30:13.0";
var third = s.split(/\s+/)[2];
// third will be "ram"
```

Answer (score 3):

If your input is so well defined (6 words, need to get third), why not just use string methods:

```
'Assigned to ram on 2010-04-22 12:30:13.0'.split(' ')[2]
```

Comment: or: `"Assigned to ram on 2010-04-22 12:30:13.0".split(" ",3).pop()`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a = "Assigned to ram on 2010-04-22 12:30:13.0"

re = /\w+\W+\w+\W+(\w+)/

alert(a.match(re)[1])
```

Comment: `\s` might make more sense than `\W` ?